# How do I install The Stanley Parable?

Tags: the-stanley-parable-2011

I decided to download [The Stanley Parable](http://www.moddb.com/mods/the-stanley-parable) after reading the [related article on our blog.](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/08/15/stanley-parable/) However, I don't know how to actually install the game.

How do I install The Stanley Parable?

Comment: The Stanley Parable is in the process of going through Steam Greenlight, so it might appear on the store soon enough!

Comment: @SadlyNot Just a quick note : http://store.steampowered.com/app/221910/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you installed Steam in the default location, you'll want to unzip the folder into `%ProgramFiles\Steam\steamapps\SourceMods`.

So, in the case of The Stanley Parable, you'll have a folder `%ProgramFiles\Steam\steamapps\SourceMods\thestanleyparable` containing at least `gameinfo.txt` and a bunch of folders.

After this, you'll have to restart Steam completely, and the mod will be in the list.

Make sure you own the Source SDK Base (which comes with almost every non-free Source game) and have it installed. (If you don't, it should install automatically when you try to launch the mod.)

Comment: In near future, Source SDK will be made freely available ([news at rockpapershotgun](http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2011/06/30/not-only-but-also-source-sdk-to-be-free/), [news at moddb](http://www.moddb.com/engines/source/news/source-sdk-is-free)).

Answer (score 3):

You can install and run it through Desura.  That's what the "Install Now" link at:

http://www.moddb.com/mods/the-stanley-parable

uses.

Comment: You'll still have to restart Steam though.

Comment: Since it's a simple matter of unzipping some files into a directory, I really don't see any reason to install a distribution client designed solely to sell promotions to assist me.